# How to use DateAdd function in Crystal Reports while in Basic Syntax mode

Tags: syntax, crystal-reports, basic

I have a formula in Crystal Reports that is written in Basic Syntax in order for it to be used with the HTML text interpretation. In one part of the code, I would like to add six months to Today's date. I know the DateAdd function can do this but I keep getting an error stating that a date is required. I know that the DateAdd function works without any problems in Crystal Syntax Mode, but I need to remain in Basic Syntax mode in order for the other code in the formula to work. What is the proper way to use DateAdd in Basic Syntax mode in Crystal Reports?

I tried using code similar to this:

```
dim sdate as date 
sdate = DateAdd("m", 6, Today) 
formula = sdate
```

When I try to save it, it returns an error and highlights the DateAdd function and the arguments `("DateAdd("m", 6, Today")` and says

> "A date is required here."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DateAdd` function returns a `DateTime`, but `sdate` is declared as `Date`.

So there are two possibilities:

1. If the time part is required, declare `sdate` as `DateTime` and use `CurrentDateTime` instead of `Today` :

   ```
   Dim sdate As DateTime
   sdate = DateAdd("m", 6, CurrentDateTime)
   formula = sdate
   ```
2. If the time part is not required, convert the result of `DateAdd` to `Date` :

   ```
   Dim sdate As Date
   sdate = CDate(DateAdd("m", 6, Today))
   formula = sdate
   ```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted to know. I only needed the date so I used option 2.